# RichTextFx VirtualizedScrollPane flickers when text wraps as you type

Tags: java, javafx, richtextfx

[image]

I have a flickering issue with RichTextFx `StyleClassedTextArea` and `VirtualizedScrollPane`. When you wrap text and keep typing, it flickers so much that you are unable to read while you type. This is a stark contrast to the regular `TextArea` scrolling. It's more pronounced than the gif above (gif fps doesn't give it justice).

I'm not sure if this is because of the `GridPane`...

Java8u212

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.fxmisc.richtext</groupId>
     <artifactId>richtextfx</artifactId>
     <version>0.10.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.fxmisc.flowless.VirtualizedScrollPane;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.StyleClassedTextArea;

public class NewFXMain extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        StyleClassedTextArea textArea = new StyleClassedTextArea();
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        TextArea textAreaFx = new TextArea();
        textAreaFx.setWrapText(true);
        
        VirtualizedScrollPane scrollpane = new VirtualizedScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollpane.setPrefWidth(300);
        
        GridPane notePane = new GridPane();

        notePane.setVgap(2);
        notePane.setHgap(6);

        notePane.add(textAreaFx, 0, 0);
        notePane.add(scrollpane, 0, 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(notePane, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Scroll flickering demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to fix the text flickering, although the scrollbars still flicker which is way more acceptable:

```
textArea.requestFollowCaret();
```